# AWS S3 get key from Friendly url

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is there a way to get 
key

using a S3 Object friendly url using **python**.
I know i can use pattern matching , but is there a aws python way to get this done.
I am familiar with something thats available in java (getKey())

> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3URI.html

For example:

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/myfolder/testimage1.jpg
```

should output

```
myfolder/testimage1.jpg
```

Comment: Note that in your example URL, `myfolder` is the bucket and `testimage1.jpg` is the key.  Unless the bucket name is provided to the *left* of the endpoint hostname (e.g. `https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com`) then it is the first component of the path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a URL, so no need for anything S3 specific. The best way is to use `urlparse`, then split by slash:

```
# For python2 use "from urlparse import urlparse" instead
from urllib.parse import urlparse
o = urlparse('https://s3.amazonaws.com/myfolder/x/y/z/testimage1.jpg')

# As this will always have a leading slash it's safe to strip
print(o.path[1:])

# Or often what you need is the s3 bucket and key separately.
bucket, key = o.path.split('/', 2)[1:]
print(bucket)
print(key)
```

Output:

```
myfolder/x/y/z/testimage1.jpg
myfolder
x/y/z/testimage1.jpg
```

Comment: Object keys in S3 don't begin with `/`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `urllib.parse`, e.g.:

```
In []:
from urllib.parse import urlparse   # Py3
# from urlparse import urlparse     # Py2

url = urlparse('https://s3.amazonaws.com/myfolder/testimage1.jpg')
url.path

Out[]:
'/myfolder/testimage1.jpg'
```

Comment: Thanks i ended up using urlparse.. my initial intention was to see if i can use any aws specific builtins